# Synchronize working directories in git submodule used in several repos

Tags: git, git-submodules

Suppose I have git repositories named `common`, `projectA`, `projectB`. Both `projectA` and `projectB` use `common` as a submodule.

When I make changes in `common`, however, only one `common` "instance" is being changed: either the one contained in `projectA`/`projectB` as a submodule, or the one cloned as a whole repository.

If I want to make changes, I have to commit to `common` first, push the changes, and then update submodules in `projectA` and `projectB`.

The problem is, I want to test changes that I'm making to `common` before commiting. And in order to do that, I have to test it with both `projectA` and `projectB`. I could theoretically commit them to some temporary branch, but it will clutter the history.

I want to make changes in `common`'s working directory in the way so these changes will be visible in `projectA` and `projectB` immediately.